# How to backport Python in Yocto build?

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, yocto, backport

I am learning how to compile custom Linux using Yocto. Currently I'm using Yocto Project 2.4 and I have added Python3 to the build. However, Python 3.5.2 was installed and I am interested in a newer version (e.g., [Python 3.8.5](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/150033/)). The reason I'm using this Yocto Project version is because I'm trying to compile a specific Linux version for [Toradex modules](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/build-u-boot-and-linux-kernel-from-source-code).

**So, how can I backport a newer Python version to my build?** The only information I've found is in [this forum post](https://forum.legato.io/t/including-python3-5-in-yocto-build/3400), that mentions something about copying python3_x.x.x.bb and python3.inc files, but it is not clear to me.

Comment: It seems Toradex does not provide BSPs for Yocto 2.3 https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/board-support-package/openembedded-core#Versions_and_SourceCode, are you sure that is the correct version? Did you also consider using a newer BSP with the kernel version you need?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I meant 2.4 (I have corrected the error). I will try Yocto 3.1. Anyway, the backporting question still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We saw your post at [Toradex Community](https://www.toradex.com/community/questions/58589/python3-update-error-on-colibri-imx6ull.html).

We are analyzing your issue because the root cause of your problem is because your newer python3 recipe requires "virtual/crypt", while the previous just had:

```
python3_3.5.3.bb:3:DEPENDS = "python3-native libffi bzip2 db gdbm openssl readline sqlite3 zlib virtual/libintl xz"
```

I'm discussing with my colleagues what could be a good approach for this case.

In the meantime, I strongly suggest you move forward to BSP 3.0.

Best regards,
André Curvello

Comment: Thank you. We will also try BSP 3.0.

Comment: I think that is the issue.


There are no providers for virtual/crypt in our default BSP 2.8, but there are at BSP 3.0.


Can you try this BSP, please?


I'll leave the same answer at our Community.

Comment: Good to know! Thank you.